# String packing unpacking in Python

Tags: python, string

I am facing the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Thread_main.py", line 681, in <module>

    fdata = struct.unpack('f', str(AObytes[i:i+3]))

struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 4
```

Here is the code line which gives error.

```
for i in range(640,8196,4):             
### === This AO bytes mapping is till for all AOS data , Last bytes are   8192,8193,8194,8195
fdata = struct.unpack('f', str(AObytes[i:i+4]))
AOSID[aop1] = fdata[0]                      
aop1 =aop1+1
```

I have defined Aobytes as this at the top.
`AObytes = [0]*8200`

Comment: The two examples you gave are different. In the first one you are getting a slice of AObytes of the length 3. In the second one a slice with length 4. The second one should work as long as you properly indent the code. The error message clearly states what the problem is. To unpack a float you need 4 characters (bytes).

Answer (score 0):

`str(AObytes[i:i+4])` is "[a, b, c, d]" so it is a string of 12 caracteres or more...

Maybe you want something like that:

```
fdata = struct.unpack('f', " ".join(str(x) for x in AObytes[i:i+4]))
fdata = fdata.split()
```

Hope this help.